# $z$ transform of $\sin( 2 \pi \frac n N + \frac \pi 4$)

Tags: z-transform

So as i said in the title i want to do the $z$ transform of: $y[n]=\sin( 2 \pi \frac n N + \frac \pi 4$)

I basically know how to do the normal z transform on a sine function but is there a way to remove the $+\frac \pi 4$?

If so how? thats the only thing i ask. Or do i have to compute it the normal way where i have to manually separate it when i do the exponential form of $\sin$?

Comment: Start with the $\sin(A+B)$ formula.

Comment: @David Yep that will do. Thanks a lot